# Is a vector field just a special case of a vector-valued function?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, definition, vector-analysis

For a vector-valued function we have
$$
\mathbf{F}:\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n
$$

However, is it correct that a vector field $\mathbf{G}$ is just a special case then $m=n$? I.e.
$$
\mathbf{G}:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n
$$

Thanks!

Comment: The definition of a vector field is usually a bit more involved, see e.g. here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2348634/does-the-definition-of-a-vector-field-include-maps-from-mathbbrn-to-mathb/2348645#2348645. The special case of a vector field on Euclidean space can be reduced to a map like your $G$.

Answer (score 0):

That is basically correct. Sometimes instead of $G:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ people require only $G:S \to \mathbb{R}^n,$ where $S \subset \mathbb{R}^n.$